# Set struct elements to values within definition

Tags: c++

The compiler seems to have no problem with this. Can I safely assume that any object I create of this type will have these defaults values?

```
struct ColorProperties
{
   bool colorRed    = true;
   bool colorBlue   = false;
   bool isRectangle = true;
};

ColorProperties myProperties;
```

Will `myProperties` automatically contain element values as noted by the struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's C++11 feature. Really it's equal to

```
struct ColorProperties {
   ColorProperties()
      : colorRed(true), colorBlue(false), isRectangle(true)
   {}

   //
};
```

You can read about this proposal [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html)

Quotes from standard.

n3376 12.6.2/8

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a
> mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no
> ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> **— if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized
> as specified in 8.5;**

```
struct A {
   A();
};

struct B {
   B(int);
};

struct C {
   C() { }

   A a;
   const B b; // error: B has no default constructor
   int i;     // OK: i has indeterminate value
   int j = 5; // OK: j has the value 5
};
```